# Android development kit SDK setup

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3, mobile-development

I am learning Android app development with Udacity. I have downloaded Android development kit but when I installed it ask for SDK setup. I have check on Youtube but there I can't find related video. Please any one could give a link for video or just point out me ways for installing it.

Comment: What link or guide you follow to install?

Comment: Look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)
.Set the "Instruction For" according to your operating system

Comment: @AnhTuan I Google searched it.

Answer (score 0):

Visit  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWa8Rf9cBps

```
     try this vedio u can find android studio installation
```

Comment: But bro this is very old video of 2k15